# how to build a full df command in coreutils in openwrt?

Tags: openwrt

I need a full df command in openwrt, and I know it was in coreutils, now I run the make in openwrt to build the coreutils, it seems that it built everything except df, so how could I modify the Makefile to build the df? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it goes like this

1. Check out the feeds repository to your local machine, see this place for URLs http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/feeds
2. modify which ever packages you want
3. edit the `feeds.conf` or the `feeds.conf.default` to source the feeds from the local copy
4. Use `./scripts/feeds update|install` to update and then install such a package,
5. `make menuconfig` to select for building